# Derived weight filtration on motivic Galois representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, higher-category-theory, derived-categories, galois-representations, motives

Thanks to modern techniques (such as the pro-etale site), we can now understand etale (co)homology of varieties and motives as "genuinely" derived (e.g. DG) Galois-equivariant objects. I'm looking for references on the weight filtration in this context, and on its (non-equivariant) splitting.

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed $\ell$-adic field. Let $\Gamma: = \text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ be the absolute Galois group. Let $C = D^-\text{Rep}_\Gamma$ be the DG category of Galois representations with coefficients in $K$, viewed as an $\infty$-category. Let $\mathcal{M}$, the derived category of "Motivic representations", be the full subcategory consisting of chain complexes with finitely many finite-dimensional cohomology groups which are *Motivic*, i.e. in the abelian subcategory of $\text{Rep}_\Gamma$ spanned (under extension and idempotent completion) by etale cohomology groups of smooth schemes (equivalently, this is the pretriangulated idempotent-complete envelope of these etale cohomology groups in an $\infty$-categorical context).

Now $\mathcal{M}$ is a symmetric monoidal stable $\infty$-category over $K$. There are two facts about this category that should be true, and which I would like to find references for (if they exist).

(1) The category $\mathcal{M}$ has a weight filtration compatible with the symmetric monoidal structure (filtration in an $\infty$-categorical sense --- e.g. formulated as a $\mathbb{G}_m$-equivariant symmetric monoidal category over $\mathbb{A}^1$).

(2) The (weight-) filtered fiber functor $\mathcal{M}\to D^-(\text{Vect})_{\text{filtered}}$ splits non-canonically as a symmetric monoidal functor (i.e. factors through a symmetric monoidal functor to graded vector spaces).

Both of these facts should follow from formal nonsense and derived Tannakian formalism, but I don't know if they have been written down.

Comment: Not relevant to your actual question, but why do you say that we needed things like the pro-etale topology before this perspective on etale cohomology was possible? Why are the traditional foundations for lisse sheaves fine for constructing a derived category with good properties, but not for the lift to a DG category? (Also, the Artin-Mazur etale homotopy type should certainly give a legitimate DG algebra structure on etale cohomology).